# AWS Glue, multiple bookmarks within same job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Lets say I have a script that is loading multiple frames with different schemas

```
job.init()
    
DefinitionDyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": [DefinitionPath], "recurse": True}, format = "csv",
     format_options= {'withHeader': True}, transformation_ctx="DefinitionBookmark")
    
    
TypeDyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": [TypePath], "recurse": True}, format = "csv",
     format_options= {'withHeader': True}, transformation_ctx="TypeBookmark")
```

I do some transformations and then I wrote to another bucket and I end the script with

job.commit()

Would both bookmarks be updated or just the first one? Is it recommended to split up bookmarks like this? most of the examples I saw only had one bookmark for each job.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is yes, based on [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html). It is saying there can be N *"state elements"* (plural) for a single state (one script with `job.commit()`). Each state is specific to each source... I am thinking of doing the same think with dynamically generated sources, all with their own state element.

> "Job bookmarks store the states for a job. Each instance of the state
> is keyed by a job name and a version number. When a script invokes
> job.init, it retrieves its state and always gets the latest version.
> **Within a state, there are multiple state elements, which are specific
> to each source, transformation, and sink instance in the script.** These
> state elements are identified by a transformation context that is
> attached to the corresponding element (source, transformation, or
> sink) in the script. The state elements are saved atomically when
> job.commit is invoked from the user script....
> **The state elements in the job bookmark are source, transformation, or sink-specific data.**"

Further down in that page there is an example JSON, with an attribute, "states", containing multiple objects.

```
{
  "job_name" : ...,
  "run_id": ...,
  "run_number": ..,
  "attempt_number": ...
  "states": {
    "transformation_ctx1" : {
      bookmark_state1
    },
    "transformation_ctx2" : {
      bookmark_state2
    }
  }
}
```

Then in [this documentation examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/programming-etl-connect-bookmarks.html#monitor-continuations-implement-examples) the code shows the `transformation_ctx` parameter for **both** source and target. Given that, there is nothing describing any limitation about handling **multiple sources**, and the following should work.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "database",
    table_name = "relatedqueries_csv",
    transformation_ctx = "datasource0"
)

datasource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "database",
    table_name = "relatedqueries1_csv",
    transformation_ctx = "datasource1"
)
```

This makes sense to use as many `transformation_ctx` parameters as needed, as long as they are uniquely named. (see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/programming-etl-connect-bookmarks.html#monitor-continuations-implement-context)

> "...transformation_ctx, which is **a unique identifier** for the ETL operator
> instance. The transformation_ctx parameter is used to identify state
> information within a job bookmark for the given operator.
> ...The transformation_ctx serves as the **key to search the bookmark state for a specific source** in your script."